# How to move the title to the bottom in a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have the following code which creates a heatmap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load dataset from seaborn
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')
flights = flights.pivot('month', 'year', 'passengers')

# Plot heatmap
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt='d', cbar_kws={'label': 'Passenger Numbers'})

# Rotate x-axis labels
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

# Set font size for colorbar title
ax1.figure.axes[-1].yaxis.label.set_size(12)
# Set font size for colorbar labels
ax1.figure.axes[-1].tick_params(labelsize=10)

# Set font for x-axis labels
plt.xticks(fontsize=12, fontstyle='oblique')
# Set font for y-axis labels
plt.yticks(fontsize=12, fontstyle='oblique')
# Set title
plt.title('Heatmap Title', fontsize=39, weight='bold')   # What needs to change here?  

# Bold 'February' in y-axis
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    if label.get_text() == 'February':
        label.set_weight('bold')

plt.show()
```

How do I move the title so that it is at the bottom of the heatmap? I have tried to follow this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351356/figure-title-set-at-bottom) by using `y=-0.01` but it doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ax.text(x,y,z)` You can use 'set_title() and 'plt.title' to set only the top, left, right and center of the title, but you can also use `ax.text(x,y,z)` to set the title. You can use `ax.text` or `ax.annotation`.

```
# plt.title('Heatmap Title', fontsize=39, weight='bold')   # What needs to change here?  
ax.text(1, 14, 'Heatmap Title',fontsize=39, weight='bold')
```

[image]